# SQL OFFSET gone wrong with placeholders in Flask

Tags: python, sql, flask

The problem looks simple but I don't know why.

This code works well:

```
qr="SELECT title, author, year FROM books ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20"
books=db.execute(qr).fetchall()
return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in books])
```

but when I uses a variable as the offset value, like this

```
paging = 20
qr="SELECT title, author, year FROM books ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :paging",{"paging":paging}
books=db.execute(qr).fetchall()
return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in books])
```

It results in error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'tuple'> instead
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paging = 20
books=db.execute("SELECT title, author, year FROM books ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :paging", paging=paging).fetchall()
return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in books])
```

More information can be found at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql